# Segmentation fault, I don't know why

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc

I have a seg fault but I don't know why. 
I know it should be working but it kee telling me there is a seg fault someone has a solution?
Please someone help I need to know for my BA.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int split_allocate(const char* s, char*** word_array){
    char c;
    char tmp[100];
    int id_s,i=0, j=0,k;
    for(id_s =0 ; (c=s[id_s])!='\0' ; id_s++){
        printf("%c\n", c);
        if(c!=' ' && c!='\t' && c!='\n'){
            tmp[i]=c;
            i++;
            printf("i if : %d\n", i);
            continue;
        }
        tmp[i]='\0';
        printf("i else : %d & tmp : %s\n", i, tmp);
        (*word_array)[j] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(i+1));
        printf("666\n");
        if(NULL== (*word_array)[j]){
            return -1;
        }
        for(k=0 ; tmp[k] != '\0' ; k++){
            (*word_array)[j][k]=tmp[k];
        }
        (*word_array)[j][k+1]='\0';
        j++;
        printf("j for : %d\n", j);
        i=0;
    }
    return j;
}

int main(void) {
    char* s = "Salut,   cet examen\n a l'air long...";
    char*** word_array;
    printf("number of words :%d\n", split_allocate(s,word_array));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `word_array` is a pointer, but *where does it point?*

Comment: Undefined behavior for using the value of an object with automatic storage duration while it is indeterminate.

Comment: Also, being a [three-start programmer](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer) is *not* something to strive for.

Comment: I have to use the three star cause it's in the prototype my professor gave us

Comment: Then you should probably pass the address of a pointer-to-pointer to `char`, i.e. have `char **word_array; split_allocate(..., &word_array);` *And* allocate memory in the function, like `*word_array = malloc(...)`

Comment: Also Your logic is wrong. E.g 1) You need to skip the spaces. 2) This will not get the last word.

Comment: What steps have you taken in attempting to debug the problem?

Comment: `(*word_array)[j][k+1] ` I bet that it does not do what you @Sam45505 think it does

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to replace

```
if(c!=' ' && c!='\t' && c!='\n')
```

with

```
if(!isspace(c))  // Iam easier and more readable
```

from `ctype.h`. Which detects all these characters

```
' '      space 
'\t'     horizontal tab 
'\n'     newline
'\v'     vertical tab 
'\f'     feed 
'\r'     carriage return
```

---

Also you should change `char*** word_array;` (three star general) to `pointer to pointer` which is enough. Then alloc memory on `heap` (*dynamic storage duration*). You didnt do it and it caused [segmentaion fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) (dereferencing uninitialzed pointer).

```
char ** word_array = malloc (sizeof(char *) * ROWS);
for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; ++i)
{
    word_array[i] = malloc (sizeof(char) * ROW_LEN);
}
```

You shouldn't cast `malloc()`'s return value because it may lead to [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Also you should check number of rows, and if needed use `realloc` to get more rows, because accessing out of bounds leads to [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

---

Instead of copying character by character use `strcpy`, since you know there is enough space. Its more readable and easier.

```
for(k=0 ; tmp[k] != '\0' ; k++){
    (*word_array)[j][k]=tmp[k];
}
```

to

```
strcpy(word_array[j], tmp); // In case word_array is char **
```

---

I can see spaces in your string but you arent skiping them, this may help

```
while ((c=s[id_s++]) && isspace(c))
    ;
```